# PCC Probe failed

Tags: boot

I'm new to Linux, and I haven't really used my laptop (Ubuntu 15.04) for anything other then ping commands and internet searches, as well as some word documents. Today I tried to boot up my computer, and it went through some boot commands. The text was bigger then normal, and ended in a "terminal" like state witht he header saying " (intramfs) " which is something I have not seen before. After a couple of reboots I've come to realize the first thing it says is PCC Probe failed and then starting system 219 or something. I researched this error and found a couple of solutions (like boot into an older version in the advanced boot menu) and nothing has worked. Does any one else have this problem? It has rendered this computer 100% useless and I kinda need it to work... 
Thanks

Comment: Can't boot into Recovery mode. Gives me something called BusyBox v1.22.1

Answer (score -1):

I had this right now, the system hanged.  I stopped the computer by holding the on-switch pressed till the pc stopped. I removed the power, pressed the on switch, then reinstalled the power chord, and restarted.
The message came again, but the recovery screen reappeared.  Useless, for I deleted all older versions last week.
Automatic startup followed, the message was that an error occured in the / and there was a problem in the cache part.  Wether an automatic repair was allowed?  Ofcourse, I answered yes. Problem solved after one more reboot.
System works perfect now.